# Compactification of Lie Group

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, compactness

Is there a way to embed a Lie Group $G$ into a compact lie Group $H$, such that the inclusion is a Lie group homomorphism?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "embed"?

Comment: I mean a monomorphism in the category of $C^{\infty}$-manifolds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f:G\to H$ be an injective Lie group morphism with $H$ compact. Since $H$ has a faithful finite dimensional representation, it suffices to compose with $f$ to obtain one for $G$.

This shows that any Lie group $G$ which does not have faithful finite dimensional representations provides an example of what you want.

Comment: Notice that a monomorphism of manifolds is an injective function.

Comment: Yes and thanks very much Mariano! :)